# How can I send a signal from a python program?

Tags: python, linux, signals

I have this code which listens to USR1 signals

```
import signal
import os
import time

def receive_signal(signum, stack):
    print 'Received:', signum

signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, receive_signal)
signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR2, receive_signal)

print 'My PID is:', os.getpid()

while True:
    print 'Waiting...'
    time.sleep(3)
```

This works when I send signals with `kill -USR1 pid`

But how can I send the same signal from within the above python script so that after 10 seconds it automatically sends `USR1` and also receives it , without me having to open two terminals to check it?

Answer (score 66):

You can use [os.kill()](https://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.kill):

```
os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGUSR1)
```

Put this anywhere in your code that you want to send the signal from.

Comment: This is useful for having a docker container commit seppuku

Comment: Can you explain what `SIGUSR1` are? Is it language Constant  or I should change it value according to the signal other program can receive ?

Comment: @Salem, it's actually an OS-level constant
(see https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)

Answer (score 6):

If you are willing to catch `SIGALRM` instead of `SIGUSR1`, try:

```
signal.alarm(10)
```

Otherwise, you'll need to start another thread:

```
import time, os, signal, threading
pid = os.getpid()
thread = threading.Thread(
  target=lambda: (
    time.sleep(10),
    os.kill(pid, signal.SIGUSR1)))
thread.start()
```

Thus, this program:

```
import signal
import os
import time

def receive_signal(signum, stack):
    print 'Received:', signum

signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, receive_signal)
signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR2, receive_signal)
signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, receive_signal)  # <-- THIS LINE ADDED

print 'My PID is:', os.getpid()

signal.alarm(10)                               # <-- THIS LINE ADDED

while True:
    print 'Waiting...'
    time.sleep(3)
```

produces this output:

```
$ python /tmp/x.py 
My PID is: 3029
Waiting...
Waiting...
Waiting...
Waiting...
Received: 14
Waiting...
Waiting...
```

Comment: where do i need to put that line in my above script

Comment: You put either of those snippets into your script at the moment you want the 10-second clock to start. For example, you could place it directly before the `while`.

Comment: i don't want to send alarm signal but `USR1` , can you give that example in my current script

Comment: It goes in the same place as `signal.alarm()`. Did you try to add it to your script?