# signal a process from another script

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyside

Basically, I need to run a script that tells a running process (python script) to do something.

I have a pyside UI with a listview that i need to update. This is executed as a subprocess of a program (Vicon Blade).
Now I need to update the listview by running a second python script from the same program.

How do I do that? I have looked into signal, subprocess and other modules, but i can't find a proper solution, where the UI stays responsive or doesn't close.

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I send a signal from a python program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15080500/how-can-i-send-a-signal-from-a-python-program)

Comment: Look at `pipe`. You can leave a `pipe` open in the main program, then, at some instant, send what you want displayed over the `pipe`. To make it asynchronous, you can connect reception as an event (see`gio_add_watch` from the `glib` library)