# How to pass complex Java objects instances to Python script

Tags: java, python, jvm, jython, py4j

I have such Java object:

```
public class MyObject {

    private Integer counter = 0;

    public void increment() {
        this.counter++;
    }

// Getters, setters

}
```

In `main()` method i am calling method `increment()`:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyObject obj = new MyObject();
        obj.increment(); // i want to call this line in python script
        // do something more
    }

}
```

Now let's image I want to pass `MyObject` instance in `main()` method to Python **script** which will call `increment()` method on passed `MyObject` instance. What is the eaziest way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should implement Signal handler in java:

http://twit88.com/blog/2008/02/06/java-signal-handling/

Then you should send Signal in python to your process in java:

[How can I send a signal from a python program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15080500/how-can-i-send-a-signal-from-a-python-program)

Signal a process is one of the easiest way to communicate between process.