# Kill application in linux using python

Tags: python, linux

I need one help regarding killing application in linux
As manual process I can use command -- ps -ef | grep "app_name" | awk '{print $2}'
It will give me jobids and then I will kill using command " kill -9 jobid".
I want to have python script which can do this task.
I have written code as

```
import os
os.system("ps -ef | grep app_name | awk '{print $2}'")
```

this collects jobids. But it is in "int" type. so I am not able to kill the application.
Can you please here?
Thank you

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15080500/how-can-i-send-a-signal-from-a-python-program

Comment: Additionally to answers, you also can use `killall` command to kill all processes matching executable name.

Answer (score 1):

```
    import subprocess
    temp = subprocess.run("ps -ef | grep 'app_name' | awk '{print $2}'", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    job_ids = temp.stdout.decode("utf-8").strip().split("\n")
    # sample job_ids will be: ['59899', '68977', '68979']
    
    # convert them to integers
    job_ids = list(map(int, job_ids))
    # job_ids = [59899, 68977, 68979]
```

Then iterate through the job ids and kill them. Use [os.kill()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.kill)

```
for job_id in job_ids:
    os.kill(job_id, 9)
```

Subprocess.run doc - https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run

Answer (score 0):

To kill a process in Python, call `os.kill(pid, sig)`, with sig = 9 (signal number for SIGKILL) and pid = the process ID (PID) to kill.

To get the process ID, use os.popen instead of os.system above. Alternatively, use `subprocess.Popen(..., stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`. In both cases, call the `.readline()` method, and convert the return value of that to an integer with `int(...)`.